# How to get the name and value of inputs in key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, key-value

I want to store the name and value of input elements in database on button click. So i want to get the name as key and value as value.

```
    <form id="form">
      <input type="text" name="fname" value="a">
      <input type="text" name="lname" value="b">
      <input type="button" value="submit">
    </form>
```

i am using this jquery code on button click to get the value.

```
    $('#form input').each(function(key, value) {
      alert(this.value);
    });
```

Please help to get the name and value as key value pair (json format).

Comment: `obj[this.name] = this.value`

Comment: complete the HTML code.

Comment: i complete the code. Waiting for your solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var obj = {};
$('#new_user_form input, #new_user_form select').each(function(key, value) {
     obj[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want individual `JSON` strings of each input use [`JSON.sringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and object literals.

```js
$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
  var obj = {};
  obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  alert(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="a">
  <input type="text" name="lname" value="b">
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Alternatively, create an array of object literals.

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/lisokicegu/1/edit?html,js,console,output)</kbd>

```
var inputs = [];

$('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
  var obj = {};
  obj[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
  inputs.push(obj);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(inputs));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
    $('#form').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submission.
      var $form = $(this);
      var url = $form.attr("action");
      console.log(url);
      var data = $form.serializeArray(); // check out this console log everything is in key-value pair.
      console.log(data);
      var $divDisplay = $("#key-value-display");
      $divDisplay.html(data);


      $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,

      }).done(function(response) {
        //work with response here.
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" action="url.php or asp.net whereever you are processing" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fname" value="a">
  <input type="text" name="lname" value="b">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<div id="key-value-display"></div>
```